# What does /*.php$ mean in robots.txt?

Tags: robots.txt

I came across a site that uses the following in its robots.txt file:

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /*.php$
```

So what does it do?
Will it prevent web crawlers from crawling the following URLs?

```
https://example.com/index.php
https://example.com/index.php?page=Events&action=Upcoming
```

Will it block subdomains too?

```
https://subdomain.example.com/index.php
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> So what does it do?

By spec it means "URLs starting with `/*.php$`", which isn't very useful. There might be engines out that which support some custom syntax for it. I know some support wild cards, but that looks like regular expression syntax and I've not heard of anything that supports that in robots.txt.

> Will it prevent web crawlers from crawling the following URLs?

By spec: No.

If anything supports regexs, then it will block the first one but not the second one.

> Will it block subdomains too?

No. Each origin is independent when it comes to robots.txt. The subdomain site would need its own copy of the resource.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like regular expressions but regular expressions [are not](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robots_exclusion_standard) in the spec. [But Google and Bing both honours](https://moz.com/learn/seo/robotstxt) wildcards (*) and end-of-url markers ($). You can [try your robots.txt rules here](http://tools.seobook.com/robots-txt/analyzer/).